# Batch Interval Optimisation

Tags: python, optimization, scipy-optimize, constraint-programming, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to optimize an advertising budget plan. The advertising budget plan is made up of 2 products, each product having adverts of different durations. The optimizer should achieve two goals:

1. Decide which weeks to place the adverts
2. How much budget to allocate for each advert, given the product budget

Here are the main user inputs:

```
Total Advertising Budget: £150K
Product-A Budget: £50K
Product-B Budget: £100K

Adverts Duration Table:
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
| Advert_No | Duration | Products |
|___________|__________|__________|
| Advert_1  | 2 Weeks  | Product_A|
| Advert_2  | 4 Weeks  | Product_A|
| Advert_3  | 5 Weeks  | Product_B|
| Advert_4  | 3 Weeks  | Product_A|
| Advert_5  | 2 Weeks  | Product_B|
| Advert_6  | 1 Weeks  | Product_A|
| Advert_7  | 3 Weeks  | Product_B|
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

Given a 10-week window, I want the optimizer to allocate the adverts optimally to maximize the objective function (i.e adverts should be optimally placed and budgets should be optimally allocated).

Below is an example of the information I want the optimizer to output:

```
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
| Weeks |   Product A   |   Product B   |
|_______|_______________|_______________|
|Week 1 |   Advert_4    |   Advert_5    |
|Week 2 |    (£15k)     |    (£50k)     |
|Week 3 |_______________|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|
|Week 4 | Advert_6 (£5k)|   Advert_7    |
|Week 5 |‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|    (£15k)     |
|Week 6 |   Advert_2    |‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾|   
|Week 7 |    (£10k)     |   Advert_3    |
|Week 8 |_______________|    (£35k)     |
|Week 9 |   Advert_1    |               |
|Week 10|    (£20k)     |               |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

Here is my attempt at the solution.  As this is an yearly advertisement budget plan broken down into weeks,  x[i] here is the variable which is the budget per week. I have been using the Scipy Optimize library, which I would like to continue using.

```
# Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so
import random

# Define Objective function (Maximization)
def obj_func(matrix):
    def prod_a_func(x):
    # Advert budgets for Prod_a is concave Exponential Function
        return (1 - np.exp(-x / 70000)) * 0.2

    def prod_b_func(x):
    # Advert budgets for Prod_a is concave Exponential Function
        return (1 - np.exp(-x / 200000)) * 0.6

    prod_a = prod_a_func(matrix.reshape((-1, 2))[:,0])
    prod_b = prod_b_func(matrix.reshape((-1, 2))[:,1])
    output_matrix = np.column_stack((prod_a, prod_b))

    return np.sum(output_matrix)


# Create optimizer function
def optimizer_result(tot_budget, col_budget_list, bucket_size_list):

    # Create constraint 1) - total matrix sum range
    constraints_list = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - tot_budget},
                        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (sum(x[i] for i in range(0, 10, 5)) - col_budget_list[0])},
                        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (sum(x[i] for i in range(1, 10, 5)) - col_budget_list[1])},
                        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x, advert_len_list[0]: [item for item in x for i in range(advert_len_list[0])]},
                        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x, advert_len_list[1]: [item for item in x for i in range(advert_len_list[1])]}]

    # Create an inital matrix
    start_matrix = [random.randint(0, 3) for i in range(0, 10)]

    # Run optimizer
    optimizer_solution = so.minimize(obj_func, start_matrix, method='SLSQP', bounds=[(0, tot_budget)] * 10,
                                     tol=0.01,
                                     options={'disp': True, 'maxiter': 100}, constraints=constraints_list)
    return optimizer_solution


# Initalise constraints
tot_budget = 150000
col_budget_list = [100000, 50000]
advert_len_list = [[2,4,3,1], [5,2,3]]


# Run Optimizer
y = optimizer_result(tot_budget, col_budget_list, advert_len_list)
advert_plan = pd.DataFrame(y['x'].reshape(-1,2),columns=["Product-A", "Product-B"])
```

**EDIT**

Here is a mathematical summary of this problem:

I have a 10x2 matrix which I need to optimize that will give me the largest ROI. Here are the constraints:

1. Sum of all the elements in the matrix is equal to the total budget
2. Sum of all the elements in a column must be equal to the column budget (for e.g sum of column 0 is equal to Prod_A budget)
3. Individual week budgets can be set (for e.g element [1,3] is equal to £10k)
4. Timing of each advertisement does not matter
5. Only the duration of the advertisement fits in the 10-week window for each product that will give maximum ROI

Comment: As already mentioned in your other question, you need integer decision variables in order to formulate the logical decisions (where to place each advert) mathematically. Scipy.optimize.minimize is for contiguous optimization problems, not integer optimization problems. That being said, there are still some details missing in your model. For instance, what is the meaning of your optimization variables? In addition, your objective (and constraints) need to be functions of a vector x (= containing your optimization variables), not a matrix.

Comment: @joni please see latest edits, forgot to add the matrix transformation i.e to convert matrix into an array which can then be passed into the optimizer - have done that now. Just wondering if this will now answer your questions?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The crucial part of an optimization model are the optimization variables and what its values represent in your model. Currently, the value of x[i] or prod_a[i] could represent anything. It's your optimization model, so you need to define them properly such that everyone understands your train of thoughts. Otherwise, we could (at least theoretically) assume x[i] represents the number of cows on some alpine meadow.

Comment: Cows? No way!...Goats on a alpine meadow....yes :)

Comment: I see what you mean. x[i] here is the variable which is the budget per week. As this is an yearly advertisement budget plan broken down into weeks.

Comment: Sadly, this question fails for the same reasons the previous one did.  Probably should be closed for lack of details...

Comment: @AirSquid apologies I am still a novice in the world of optimization. Please bear with me. I will try to add the required details.

Comment: @Reinderien please see latest edits

Comment: @Reinderien my solution doesn't work as this was just to show an attempt was made.

Comment: That's fine, but please show the current output and why you believe it to be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to try and be charitable here, so bear with me.

> Decide which weeks to place the adverts

is a lie, and expressly *not* something that your code attempts. You say yourself that *Timing of each advertisement does not matter*, so I ignore this.

You should not define functions for `prod_a_func` and `prod_b_func`. Among other reasons, it's slower than vectorisation, and is non-generalisable to a higher product count. Those mystery parameters `70000`, `0.2` etc. need to be put into named vectors and used in a single ROI expression.

One of the most significant problems with the objective function is that it claims to maximize, but doesn't maximize. To do that you need to negate your sum.

Your constraints are confused. They all need to be removed and replaced with one linear constraint: the total budget used for each product is *at most* the product budget passed into the function. Budgets aren't generally "you must spend this much"; they're "you must spend at most this much". The grand total constraint is redundant given the individual product constraints.

The initial values are a very bad idea. Don't pass random data here; that gets you a non-deterministic optimisation. We can make a better guess, and in fact since this entire problem is so trivial, the optimised value ends up equalling the guess: divide the budget equally among all advertisements.

Don't set a specific method, tolerance and iteration count unless you have a very good reason. Delete all of that.

`* 10` is not a good idea. Your bounds need to be based on the function inputs.

```py
import string
from typing import Sequence

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds, LinearConstraint


def obj_func(flat: np.ndarray, A: np.ndarray) -> float:
    # These mystery constants should be given better names and passed in as arguments
    a = ((70_000,), (200_000,))
    b = ((0.2,), (0.6,))

    # Convert 'flat' into a matrix of n_products by n_advertisements with zeros where the
    # advertisement is not for that product.
    expenditure = np.zeros_like(A, dtype=float)
    expenditure[A] = flat

    # advert ROI for product is a concave exponential function
    roi = (1 - np.exp(-expenditure / a)) * b

    # to maximize, this must be negated
    return -roi.sum()


def optimizer_result(
    product_budgets: Sequence[float],
    advert_weeks: Sequence[tuple[int, ...]],
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # the total number of advertisements
    n_adverts = sum(len(p) for p in advert_weeks)
    n_products = len(advert_weeks)
    # the number of weeks over which the campaign runs
    n_weeks = sum(advert_weeks[0])

    # This is a selection matrix used in both the linear budget
    # constraint and to spread the budget decision variable
    A = np.zeros((n_products, n_adverts), dtype=bool)
    start = np.empty(n_adverts)
    upper = np.empty(n_adverts)

    i_advert = 0
    for i_product, (budget, weeks) in enumerate(zip(product_budgets, advert_weeks)):
        next_advert = i_advert + len(weeks)
        # wherever this product has an advertisement, write a 1
        A[i_product, i_advert: next_advert] = 1
        # the initial value for each budget is the product's
        # budget evenly distributed over each advertisement
        start[i_advert: next_advert] = budget / len(weeks)
        # the upper bound for each advertisement budget is the budget for the entire product
        upper[i_advert: next_advert] = budget
        i_advert = next_advert

    solution = minimize(
        fun=obj_func,
        args=(A,),
        x0=start,
        bounds=Bounds(lb=np.zeros_like(upper), ub=upper),
        constraints=LinearConstraint(
            A=A,
            lb=np.zeros(n_products),
            ub=product_budgets,
        ))
    assert solution.success

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        columns=pd.Index(name='product', data=tuple(string.ascii_uppercase[:n_products])),
        index=pd.RangeIndex(name='week', start=1, stop=n_weeks+1),
        dtype=float,
    )

    i_advert = 0
    for i_product, weeks in enumerate(advert_weeks):
        toweek = 0
        for week_span in weeks:
            next_week = toweek + week_span
            # the displayed budget for this product and advertisement on this week is the
            # advertisement's budget divided evenly among its week span
            df.iloc[toweek: next_week, i_product] = solution.x[i_advert] / week_span
            toweek = next_week
            i_advert += 1

    return df


advert_plan = optimizer_result(
    product_budgets=(100_000, 50_000),
    advert_weeks=((2, 4, 3, 1), (5, 2, 3)),
)
print(advert_plan)
```

```
product             A            B
week                              
1        12500.000000  3333.333333
2        12500.000000  3333.333333
3         6250.000000  3333.333333
4         6250.000000  3333.333333
5         6250.000000  3333.333333
6         6250.000000  8333.333333
7         8333.333333  8333.333333
8         8333.333333  5555.555556
9         8333.333333  5555.555556
10       25000.000000  5555.555556
```

Again, this optimisation is a no-op and equals the initial guess.